# Selenium invalid selector exception : Locator startegy 'name' is not supported for this session

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, appium

I 'm automating my tests using Appium and TestNG in java running in the browser of ipad simulator.
The problem is that when i try to tap this code to find an element : `By.name("person");` the action is not executed !

Comment: You probably should add more code to show what you are doing. It's hard to tell from what you've shown.

Comment: Use By.accessibilityid()

Comment: name selector is deprecated in Appium 1.5.2. Are you using latest 1.5.2. if yes replace name with *id*. else as said by @HemChe, use accessibilityId();

Comment: I think the problem isn't in code, the only focus is in that line :  driver.findelement(By.name("person")); because the problem in locator "by name" not in the code itself, it works ine with other locators, id, css, tagname... just i wanted to know why this is not supported for by name: i'm using appium with npm, version 1.5.1

Comment: as HemCHe and Shiva said, By. name is deprecated.....so instead of By.name, use By.accessibilityid().... you can use name inside this By.accessibilityid()

Comment: @noor : Yes i have found other locators instead of by name, just i wanted to know the reason, and if this is problem of appium version ? or because it's a web application on browser ? or because an ios app?

Comment: this api is just deprecated emna, thats why u can not use this api in appium latest vaersion....but why the appium developers deprecated this api....the reason is known to them

Answer (score 1):

From 1.5 Appium version -  "name" locator got deprecated "Remove long-deprecated name locator strategy".

We can click the display text like this :

```
MobileElement makeTextLocartor = (MobileElement) wd

.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"+<your_text>+\")");

makeTextLocartor.click();
```

This link will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Comment: Thanks for your try !